# Leer 1KB de cada archivo de una carpeta

Tags: c

necesito leer el primer KB de cada archivo que haya dentro de una carpeta, consigo mostrar por pantalla los nombres de todos los archivos pero despues no consigo saber que hacer para leer uno a uno cada archivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "antispam.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* Variables */
DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *direntp;

if(argc != 2){
    printf("Argumentos invalidos\n");
    exit(1);
}else{
    /* Abrimos el directorio */
    dirp = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (dirp == NULL){
    printf("Error: No se puede abrir el directorio\n");
    exit(2);
    }

    /* Leemos las entradas del directorio */
    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        /*  FILE *f = fopen(direntp->d_name, "r");*/

          printf("%s\n",direntp->d_name);
    }
    /*
printf("numero de argumentos %d\n",(int)argc);
printf("argumento 1 %s\n",argv[0]);
printf("argumento 2 %s\n",argv[1]);
*/

    /* Cerramos el directorio */
    closedir(dirp);

}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo reemplazando la linea:

```
printf("%s\n",direntp->d_name);
```

Con algo como lo siguiente:

```
char path[1024];
char firstKB[1024];
sprintf(path, "%s/%s", argv[1], direntp->d_name);
FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
fread(firstKB, 1024, 1, f);
// haz algo con el primer KB
```